# Hide element when clicking anywhere outside it

Tags: jquery

I want hide div when user click anywhere in the page but not on the div.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(document).not('.me').click(function () {
        $('.me').hide()
    })
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="me" style="width:200px; height:200px; background:#F00">
test
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following script to achieve this..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).click(function (event) {
            var target = $(event.target);
            if (!target.parents().andSelf().is('.me')) {
                $(".me").hide();
            }
        });
 </script>
```

The above syntax is to check, if the parent is other than the div(`here it's me`), than only hide the div.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Stopping the propagation is a much better and performant solution. This one might hurt with a bigger DOM if you have to check all the parents all the time...

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).click(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".me");

    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it adding a click event to the `body` or `html` elements as well as preventing the propagation of the click event over your `div` element:

```
$(function () {
    //bye bye lovely div :)
    $('html, body').click(function(){
       $('.me').hide();
    });

    //let's avoid the click propagation to the body or html
    $('.me').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
     });
});
```

[LIVING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/imac/SJqPf/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) :

```
$(function(){
    $(document).click(function(){
       $(".me").hide();
    });
    $(".me").click(function(e){
       e.stopPropagation(); 
    });
});
```

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NTME6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $(document).click(function(){
        $('.me').hide()
    })
    $('.me').click(function(){
        return false;
    })
})
```